# How i can summary data in another tab in new format with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have raw data in many rows and I want to summarize this data to a new tab in the new desired format like a picture:

1. [Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYG7x.png)
2. [New format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyJjD.png)

```js
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets();
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  var values = [["Shop order", "Part number", "Workstation", "Count workstation"]];
  var range = yourNewSheet.getRange("A1:D1");
  range.setValues(values);
  
  var sheet1Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var columnF = sheet1Sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
  var columnB = sheet1Sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var columnC = sheet1Sheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues();

}}
```

I don't know how to write the code to change my data to a new format.

Comment: Aside from the other issues, the files that you've linked to aren't accessible

Comment: I'm sorry it my first time to ask in stack overflow. I edited this question and add more of information done.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a working code snippet that calculates the SUM for each `shop_order`- `part_number` combination by

- assigning the combination of `shop_order` and `part_number` to an array, with every row being converted to an array entry
- estimating how many time every combination occurs and assigns the result to an entry of the array sum
- checking if the combination occurred for the first time
- populating the second sheet with rows containing `part_number`, `shop_order` and `sum` a single time for each combination

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet43');
  var rowNumber=sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var columnShopOrder=6;
  var columnPartNumber=2;
  var shopOrder=sheet.getRange(2,columnShopOrder,rowNumber,1).getValues();
  var partNumber=sheet.getRange(2,columnPartNumber,rowNumber,1).getValues();

  var count=[]
  for(var a=0;a<partNumber.length;a++)
  {
   count.push(shopOrder[a][0]+partNumber[a][0]) 
  }
  var sum=[];
  var element;
  for(var j=0;j<count.length;j++){
    element=count[j];
    var indexes = [], i, occurence;
    for(i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
      if (count[i] == element){
         indexes.push(i);
        if(count.indexOf(element)==j){
          occurence='first';
        }     
      }
    }
    if(occurence=='first') {
     sum.push([indexes.length])
     } else {
       sum.push([0])
     }
    occurence='existing';  
  }
  for(var x=0;x<sum.length;x++){
    if(sum[x][0]!=0)
    {
      sheet2.appendRow([shopOrder[x][0], partNumber[x][0], sum[x][0]]);
    }
  }
}
```

> As you can see, the code is already a little convoluted with multiple
>   loops, arrays and nesting. If you want to further amplify it by
>   counting also the sums for different work stations separately, you
>   would need to implement additional nested arrays and loops.

You might want to look into the usage of [pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. But ...
I don't know the way to write loop for use workstation to my format.

Comment: The way I can think of would be to iterate through all occurrences of work station and count how much each one occurs, build a sum of occurrences - just like done in the code above for the total sum, but for each workstation separately, and then push all this information into a string. Pretty coding intensive, this is why I suggest to you to think about other solutions how you might represent your data, or summarize it with a pivot table, which can be done manually, from the UI.